# STR trees and how they are different from an R-tree?

Tags: tree, r-tree

What is an STR tree ? How is it different from an R-tree ? . Whenever I search for 'STR-trees' I'm getting the search result of an R-tree . Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is a Java class for query-only R-trees called STRtree that uses the Sort-Tile-Recursive algorithm.  Here is a link: http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/index/strtree/STRtree.html

Answer (score 7):

Can you provide a **reference** for an STR-tree? I've never seen it mentioned.

I only know the Sort-Tile-Recursive bulk-loading strategy for the R-tree. So it *is* an R-tree then.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, STR-tree is a spatio-temporal R-tree, which is mainly used for a moving object, see [Novel Approaches to the Indexing of Moving Object Trajectories](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/928c/82d0cf89d3d80e247fe56ab92e271d77540b.pdf). STRtree is a packed R-tree by using Sort-Tile-Recursive, see [STR: A Simple and Efficient Algorithm for R-Tree Packing](https://www.cs.odu.edu/%7Emln/ltrs-pdfs/icase-1997-14.pdf). The abbreviation STRtree is not commonly used.